# How to make a wood gear?

Tags: wood, tool-selection

I want to know how I could make wooden gears at home without the need of a CNC or a laser. What tool should I use, what are the steps to making one?

Comment: [Have at it](http://woodgears.ca/index.html).

Comment: @grfrazee Here I was about to refer OP to woodgears.ca, but I had a sneaking suspicion that I should check your link first. If you want to avoid clicking around on the website, [here's the actual article on how to make plywood gears](http://woodgears.ca/gear_cutting/plywood_gears.html).

Comment: @Doresoom - I clicked the "Planetary Gears" link after reading through the article you linked. **Don't do it!!!** Unless, of course, you have a _lot_ of time to spend wandering down a fascinating mechanical rabbit hole!

Comment: @FreeMan Haha, yes! Epicyclic drivetrains are really interesting. It's a bit more familiar to me already though, since vibration-based drivetrain condition monitoring is what I do for a living. Although Matthias' gear ratio calculations can be made a bit simpler (in my opinion) by using the [superposition method](http://www.efunda.com/designstandards/gears/gears_epicyclic_ratio.cfm). :)

Answer (score 3):

All you really need is a template and a way to shape inside corners.

Shaping the inside corners can be done with a file, a strip sander, a bandsaw,...

To create one you make the template of the gear you want glue it to the wood and then remove wood up to the line. With a bandsaw you can first cut out the outside circle and then cut out the spurs. you could also use a drill to remove most of the material between the teeth.